Duck DB - can I mask passwords in connection string
When atttaching a DB like this:
ATTACH 'dbname=mydb user=myuser host=myserverhost password=mypassword port=5432' AS my alias (TYPE postgres);
How can I use a variable or mask the password "mypassword" in some way? Does DuckDb already have a good way to do this? I cannot find it in the docs.

"mask" to what? Where would you like to display the connection string but not the password?

Have you ever used ducks ?
